# How to create a database user and grant it permission to create trigger for specific table only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, user-permissions

I'm testing my project and I have to write permissions unit test for one of its components. Unit tests start from creating temporary database and table. I want to write SQL code which creates new user for temporary database and grants it permission to create trigger (single function which component does) just only for temp test table. This user will be used by my component. How can I do this? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this SQL code. It works for me:

```
USE [YourDatabase];
CREATE USER YourUser FOR LOGIN YourLogin;
GRANT ALTER ON dbo.YourTable TO [YourUser]
```